# Windows Explorer - Show encoding column

Tags: windows, windows-10, explorer

I have many folders with text files, and i would like to add a column in the "Details view" of my windows explorer to show the encoding "ASCII, UTF-8, ..."

Is there any simple way to do that ?

EDIT:
If you think that it's impossible to do it using windows explorer, do you know an explorer that would do that ?

Comment: The character encoding is not stored. It's up to you to maintain that knowledge. (You could use [alternate data streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams) to do it. But, any way you do it, it's going to be novel. A better alternative would be to not use text files.)

Comment: thank you @TomBlodget, do you know some kind of explorer that would show the encoding without having to open the file with a text editor

Comment: An editor is blithely guessing because it can count on you to stop or change it if the guess is wrong. You can get other guessing tools or write your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally found out a solution, this great app lists encodings of files for a choosen directory, it saved me a lot of time:

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=encodingchecker

**EDIT:**

The above link is dead, try this instead:
https://github.com/amrali-eg/EncodingChecker

Thanks @ole-eh-dufour

Comment: The link is dead, try https://github.com/amrali-eg/EncodingChecker instead